# can managed identity be used between service hosted in AKS and client app hosted as app service

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice

I have `asp.net core` web api app which is hosted in `Azure Kubernetes Service` and the web api endpoints is secured with `Azure Active Directory (AAD)`. Following the below article,

https://dotnetplaybook.com/secure-a-net-core-api-using-bearer-authentication/

Now I have another asp.net core web api application (Gateway) which is hosted as `Azure App Service` and this is a client application for above microservice which is hosted in AKS.

I have registered the client app (Gateway) also in `AAD` and using `secret` and using this gateway and microservices authenticated and works.

Since AKS hosted microservices talks with Azure App service, can I use `Managed Identity` so that I don't need to do `secret` management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to clarify, your service deployed in Azure App Service is calling your application deployed in AKS.

If your Azure App Service is acting on its own behalf (ie: it is a daemon app, and users dont interact with that app), then yes, you can simply use a Managed Identity for that App Service and give that identity the API permissions for the app in AKS.

--an update to the above

I wrote some additional details that walks through all steps to achieve this, take a look at this post: https://blog.identitydigest.com/single-tenant-daemon-managed-identity/ . It also has a pointer to a very rudimentary code sample.

Comment: Yes. my Azure App Service is acting on its own behalf (ie: it is a daemon app, and users dont interact with that app). how to set the permission? any article or demo code appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The quick answer is: follow the directions in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-assign-app-role-managed-identity-powershell. But if more details are useful, I have written something up that I will link to my original answer

Comment: Hi @udayxhegde, how to cache the token and refresh it automatically? Is there anything built-in available with `azure.identity`? I asked a new question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547953/how-to-cache-and-refresh-managed-identity-token